# Laws of equivalence to show $ \forall x \in U. (P(x) \rightarrow \neg Q(x)) \equiv \neg \exists x \in U. (P(x) \land Q(x)) $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

Using laws of equivalence

$$ \forall x \in U. (P(x) \rightarrow \neg Q(x)) \equiv \neg \exists x \in U. (P(x) \land Q(x)) $$

show that these are logically equivalent.

Comment: What you have tried? where you are facing problem to show this?

Comment: $\lnot (p\land q)\iff\lnot p\lor\lnot q\iff p\to\lnot q$

Comment: I don't know what the notation looks like with the quantifiers after each step and i'm not sure what to do with it to after using the formula @Isah used

Comment: See my answer, hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

$\forall x \in U. (P(x) \rightarrow \neg Q(x)) \equiv \neg \exists x \in U. (P(x) \land Q(x))$

So (using your notations),

$$\color{blue}\forall x \in U. (P(x) \rightarrow \neg Q(x))$$ $\equiv$ $$\color{blue}{\neg \exists} x \in U.\lnot (P(x)\color{red} \to\lnot Q(x))$$ $\equiv$ $$\neg \exists x \in U. \lnot(\color{red}\lnot P(x)\color{red} \lor \lnot Q(x))$$ 
$\equiv$ $$\neg \exists x \in U. (P(x) \land Q(x))$$